# If an object is not in array add to array

Tags: flutter

I have an array which contains my body, now I want to check if this array contains this object remove and add new value, otherwise add it to my body list. how can I set this condition in flutter?

this is my body:

```
createSwitchButtonBody(int index) {
body.add({
  "value":
      "product_attribute_${getBuilderResponseModel.data!.productAttributes![attributeValueIndex].id}",
  "key": getBuilderResponseModel
      .data!.productAttributes![attributeValueIndex].values![index].id,
});
print(body);
update();}
```

I wanna when make switchButton value equals to true add an object to array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
List myArray = [5, 7 , 10];
int bodyObject = 7;
int newObject = 12;
int i = 0;
bool isNotFoundYet = true;
while(i < (myArray.length-1) && isNotFoundYet){
  if (myArray[i] == bodyObject) {
    myArray.removeAt(i);
    myArray.add(newObject);
    isNotFoundYet = false;
  }
  else i++;}
if (isNotFoundYet) myArray.add(newObject);
```

Comment: my body is something like this:
createSwitchButtonBody(int index) {
    body.add({
      "value":
          "product_attribute_${getBuilderResponseModel.data!.productAttributes![attributeValueIndex].id}",
      "key": getBuilderResponseModel
          .data!.productAttributes![attributeValueIndex].values![index].id,
    });
    print(body);
    update();
  }

Comment: Yes, same logic. Just adjust your IF condition to check whatever `id` you have in your body object:   `if (myArray[i].id == bodyObject.id) {`